# Julia, type interdependencies

Tags: julia

How would I resolve something like this:

```
type Foo
    x::Goo
    end

type Goo
    y::Foo
    end
```

I feel like this is a compile vs run-time issue, is there a way to pre-declare types so that the interpreter/compiler/whatever doesn't throw a LoadError?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use an abstract type

```
abstract GooLike

type Foo
     x::GooLike
end

type Goo <: GooLike
     y::Foo
end
```

or parametric version

```
type Foo{T<:GooLike}
    x::T
end
```

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/269) (as of the 2014-08-08) about circular dependencies.